# ¿Cómo obtener la descripción de un sensor?

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando una aplicación descriptiva de todos los sensores que tiene el teléfono, ya obtengo una lista de los nombres de los sensores, pero ¿como obtengo la descripción de los sensores?

Por ejemplo uno de los nombres que me arroja es st480 ¿como obtengo la descripción de ese sensor?

Comment: Si parte de la descripción del sensor es el tipo, puedes ver la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html), ya que se muestran ejemplo de como obtener los datos de los sensores. Ahora si quieres saber a que sensor específicamente corresponde ese modelo, creo que la única forma es consultar un servicio externo que mantenga una lista de sensores y modelo/características o mantenerla tu mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Comentas que ya obtuviste una lista de los sensores, lo que requieres es obtener la "descripción", este dato no esta [disponible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) para obtener mediante un método del SDK, tal vez lo más cercano sea la descripción del tipo, mediante [getStringType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getStringType()) , disponible desde API 20, por ejemplo:

```
SensorManager mgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensors = mgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
    Log.d("Sensor nombre: ", sensor.getName());
    Log.d("Sensor tipo: ", sensor.getStringType());
}
```

obtienes :

```
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Gravity
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.gravity
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Tilt
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.tilt_detector
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Rotation Vector-Wakeup Secondary
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.rotation_vector
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Geomagnetic Rotation Vector-Wakeup Secondary
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.geomagnetic_rotation_vector
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Orientation-Wakeup Secondary
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.orientation
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Linear Acceleration-Wakeup Secondary
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.linear_acceleration
Sensor nombre:: Invensense Gravity-Wakeup Secondary
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.gravity
Sensor nombre:: Device Position Classifier
Sensor tipo:: android.sensor.pick_up_gesture
...
...
...
```